# Adding JavaScript code into angular template expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular template that displays the unix timestamp, which is a number type:

```
<span>{{timestamp}}</span>
```

That displays like:

```
<span>1391139098314</span>
```

Instead of the number though, I want a nice string to display:

```
<span>1/30/2014 7:32:37 PM</span>
```

I thought it would be as easy as changing the template to what you see below, but that doesn't work.

```
<span>{{ new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString() }}</span>
```

Can someone tell me what I need to do in my template instead of what is not working, shown directly above?

Comment: <span>{{ myFunctionOnTheScopeThatReturnsA(timestamp) }}</span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [date filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3adate):

```
<span>{{timestamp | date:'M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'}}</span>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/dYSl8NcJbLsYoQ2WSopH?p=preview)